# Can i have 2 services (.svc) in one Azure WCFWebRole?

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles

I have my Azure cloud solution, with a WCFWebRole, and i created 2 services (.svc).
On localhost they both work great.

But when i publish my solution to Azure, only one of the .svc's are uploaded

What am i missing?
I read a lot of threads about people combining all their service interfaces into one .svc file for some reason, but i see no point in that, if worst comes i will divide the .svc files into 2 WebRoles (which will be a waste, and probably not possible when thinking about it, because i have Windsor Castle and Nhibernate configured on the WebRole, so Lifestyles won't be kept between the webroles)

It doesn't seem like a big dig having more than one .svc when working on localhost...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one .svc WCF service in a single WCF project assigned to a single Azure Cloud Services Web Role.

[This GitHub project](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/WCFAzureCloudServiceSample) is a sample of such a project that, after configured with storage credentials in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and when deployed to a Windows Azure Cloud Service, will answer to requests to both Service1.svc?wsdl and Service2.svc?wsdl.

To verify if your .svc files are being uploaded in the package, you can go to the bin\Release\app.publish directory under your cloud project and extract the .cspkg file (it is in ZIP format). Inside it you'll find a large .cssx file. Extract it as well. Inside this file look into the approot directory. You'll find the project files there. The same files should be found in the csx\Release\roles under your cloud project.

If the .svc files are indeed being uploaded and they're not executing in the cloud environment, check your WCF bindings and endpoints.

You may also activate Remote Desktop in a single development cloud instance and connect to the server to verify logs and events, and to inspect the application directories.

Comment: That was a really informative answer, i will check the folders you said, but from what i remember it didn't upload the 2nd .svc, what do you do if the package doesn't contain it?, i will check the github project too to check for differences

Comment: @RoyiMindel, if the package doesn't contain the .svc that probably would indicate an issue with the solution, the project, the build or the deployment. But please verify first if it is in the .cspkg file and if possible Remote Desktop into the server to check the application directory and the event logs.